# AWS Lambda event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId returning null

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am trying to get the Cognito username from within my lambda function. I have enabled my api gateway to use "Use Lambda Proxy integration". It is now returning the identity object but cognitoIdentityId is returning null?!?

Is there something I am missing?

**UPDATE**
As usual, I missed something vital! On that POST API, I did not select the Authorization user pool. DUH!

Comment: I think I need to enable "Invoke with caller credentials" but it is greyed out?

Answer (score 0):

using event['requestContext']['authorizer'].claims.sub worked for me.
I also had to send the jwt id token as Authorization Header for the API call.